# How can I fetch data points belonging to a map bounding box?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, deck.gl

I am plotting thousands of data points on a map, and at any point I want to fetch the data points falling in a particular map bounding box. *For example*, attached below is the complete view of the available data points,
[image: Whole View]

If I zoom in a bit, i will have fewer points and I want to fetch the data associated with those points.[image: Zoomed in view]

How I am **approaching** this is *fetching the bounding box of the map, and then checking the coordinates of each point if they belong in that bounding box*. Sample code is below,

```
const data = [
    {lat: 33.93911, lng: 67.709953},
    {lat: -11.2027, lng: 17.8739},
    {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2093},
    {lat: -42.8821, lng: 147.3272},
    {lat: 26.0275, lng: 50.55}
    ]
const boundingBox = window.map.getMapBounds();
const result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(/* point lies within bounding box */) {
        result.push(point);
    }
}
```

How can I optimise it or is there a better solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `bbox-polygon` and `boolean-intersects` from `turf`:

- Use `onViewStateChange` from deck instance within a `debounce` function so it won't be executed too often
- Create a polygon from the deck `viewState` using `@turf/bbox-polygon`
- Pass it to `@turf/boolean-intersects` with the whole features using `filter` JS method

```js
import { WebMercatorViewport } from '@deck.gl/core';
import bboxPolygon from '@turf/bbox-polygon';
import intersects from '@turf/boolean-intersects';

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, ms);
  };
}

function getViewport(viewState) {
  const bounds = new WebMercatorViewport(viewState).getBounds()
  return bboxPolygon(bounds)
}

function getViewportFeatures({ viewState }) {
  const viewport = getViewport(viewState)
  const viewportFeatures = features.filter((f) => intersects(f, viewport))
  console.log(viewportFeatures) // Your target
}

<DeckGL
  ...
  onViewStateChange={debounce(getViewportFeatures, 500)}
/>
```

**Advanced**: if your data is really big, you can use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)